# Create a subirectory within multiple directories

Tags: terminal, macintosh, mkdir

I have a directory containing several folders with different names, and I need to create a subdirectory in each individual folder.

The path for one of the folders looks like this:

`/Volumes/Server1/Craft/2OQ/Dom_Curr/EN/CT_1`

There are multiple `CT_xyz` (`CT_1` through `CT_124`) folders in the `EN` directory, and I need to put a subdirectory in each `CT` folder like this:

`/Volumes/Server1/Craft/2OQ/Dom_Curr/EN/CT_1/5Misc/Permissions`

The `5Misc/Permissions` folders need to go in each individual folder.

Comment: Hey, just revisiting some questions. Would you mind accepting an answer so other users will know the issue is solved? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change into the `/Volumes/Server1/Craft/2OQ/Dom_Curr/EN` directory:

```
cd /Volumes/Server1/Craft/2OQ/Dom_Curr/EN
```

Then run the following:

```
for D in CT_*
do
    mkdir -p ${D}/5Misc/Permissions
done
```

This will add the subdirectories to every directory in the `EN` directory that begins with `CT_`

Comment: ... Except when you happen to also have files with named that begin with `CT_`. :)

Comment: Yes, except for in those instances.

Comment: ... Which is why you should enclose the inner statement in `if [ -d "$D" ]; then ... fi`.

Comment: Stephen, this worked perfectly for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Or change the loop to `CT_*/.` which will only match directories... but may follow symlinks :-)

Comment: @AdriennePayne - "I_GNU_it_all_along" wrote the answer (I just tidied it up a little).  They get the credit.

Comment: Such chivalry :)

Comment: @StephenHarris Oh, haha, woops.  Thanks for tidying then.

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along And thank you!!!  This really helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the list fuction of bash integrated into the usual mkdir:

```
mkdir /Volumes/Server1/Craft/2OQ/Dom_Curr/EN/CT{1..124}
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/731721/is-there-a-way-to-create-multiple-directories-at-once-with-mkdir

Original author: https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind